# Our codebase has the Plaid funding_account_id committed to git. Is that already an encrypted id or should I change it because its exposed now?

Tags: plaid

The Plaid documentation does not explicitly state whether the funding_account_id is encrypted or not nor does it explicitly state whether its a secret that should be encrypted in our app. I'm trying to determine if this is sensitive data that I should recreate since its been exposed in our app.

I parsed through all of the Plaid documentation, did a google search for anyone else that may have this question and used Phind.com to parse through the internet for anything I may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

The `funding_account_id` is not considered a security-sensitive identifier and does not provide access to any data, it is used only to disambiguate between funding accounts when you have multiple funding accounts to choose from. In general, fields in the Plaid API ending with `_id` are not considered security-sensitive. Security-sensitive identifiers (and here I'm only talking about identifiers, rather than obviously sensitive fields, like those that directly contain user personal information) would be persistent fields ending in `_token` (such as a `user_token`, `access_token`, etc.) as well as your API secret.

Comment: Thank you Alex! I want to share this with my team to reassure them. Do you know of a place where plaid has documented that fields ending in `_id` are not considered security-sensitive? I really appreciate your response!

Comment: @LaurenAlbert yes, this is discussed in Storing API Data https://plaid.com/docs/api/#storing-api-data which distinguishes between ids and tokens and the different sensitivity levels of those two types of fields

Comment: Thanks so much @alex!